# Device dependant scale/zoom pixelating behavior on web app background png

Tags: image, png, hybrid-mobile-app, zooming

With a hybrid app in phonegap there is a problem when testing on specific devices.

This occurs with all .png images, for explanatory purposed a 650px x 650px is described.

The image loads as the background of a  at a much smaller size than its native resolution.

- A user can select an image and pinch gesture to zoom in /scale up, CSS.
- This works great in develoment and when tested on various devices it
  is just fine.  The image zooms in and the clarity is what you would
  expect.
- On a particular device when the user zooms in the image is grainy as
  if the orrigional small representation was its maximum size so when
  scalled up there is loss of detail, sharp edges becoming jagged and
  blurred,... If the app changes screen, so we make the current 
  display:none, and then changes back, the image is in its full
  glorious resolution just like every other device.

So we have one device failure but we don't know how many others are out there that will exibit the same behaviour.

We have tried forcing GPU rendering, setting image-resolution CSS, loading the image at max size and scaling down but nothing has worked.

I want to avoid reloading the image or simulating a screen change.  This will introduce load on other devices that don't need it.

Does anyone know how to fix or prevent?
What device settings that we can in app change or detect may cause this?
Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

I tried various things that did not work. A lot of things have been omitted and working out what did cause a difference lead to the solution.

Resetting the background image to itself.

```
style = ele.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(ele, false);
bg = style.backgroundImage;     // get bg image URL
ele.style.backgroundImage=bg;  // reasign bg image URL
```

This did nothing.

So I tried swapping the style sheet to one with a differently named identical image, again nothing.

Then I set the display to "none" and back to "block".  Unfortunately if I did not put a timeout between these activities the app did not bother redrawing.

So

```
ele.style.display = "none";
ele.display = "block";
```

did not work.

Neither did

```
ele.style.display = "none";
setTimeout(function() {ele.display = "block";}, 0);
```

When I increased the wait to 4 ms it worked, hurrah!
Except there is a noticeable blank period on the screen > 4ms.

So I figured what would cause a redraw without having a visual effect.  There are lots of things that have minor effects in pixel judder or borders.  I was about to test setting a background color change, which should not be noticed because the background is an image then I thought, inline-block and block have no different visual effect for my app so I tried.

```
ele.style.display = "inline-block";
setTimeout(function() {ele.display = "block";}, 10);
```

I put the timer back in because it did not always work without it.
Ta da, crystal clear image and no other visual disturbance or loss of responsiveness.
Better still in the devices that don't show picture degradation there is no loss of performance.